# Critical points of $y=x^2 (\ln x)^3$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, maxima-minima

What are the critical points of

$$y = x^2 \ln^3(x)\;?$$

The derivative is: $y'=2\ln^3(x) +3\ln^2(x)$ (after simplifying the expression)

Which is the minumum?

It is clear that the answer is $x=1$ while comparing to $0.$

Though the real answer is $\dfrac 1 { \sqrt{e^3}}$.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I don't have a lot of faith in your derivative.

Comment: I think it is better to write $(\ln x)^3$ than $\ln^3 x$ if the former is what you mean, since the notation $\ln^3 x$ is sometimes taken to mean $\ln(\ln(\ln x))). \qquad$

Comment: It's clear that *one* answer is x=1.

Comment: Do you think that $(x^2+1)x$ is the same as $x$, because $x^2+1$ doesn't vanish? Well, the former is a degree $3$ polynomial, the latter has degree $1$: they are *not* the same. You can't “remove $x$” from your derivative.

Comment: @egreg no I don't, clearly you misinterpreted the idea behind the post...

Comment: @user6394019 You write $y'=2\ln^3(x) +3\ln^2(x)$, which is wrong, because you ***can't*** remove $x$.

Comment: actually I can remove it after comparing it to 0. because x can't be equal to zero by definition of ln(in(0)==>-infinty)

Comment: The derivative is $ y'= x (\ln x)^2( 2 + 3 \ln x)$, Now set this equal to zero. $x=1$ cannot be an extremum since the function changes its sign there.

Answer (score 5):

You are wrong about $y'$; it is $3x\log^2(x)+2x\log^3(x)$. Therefore, $y'=0$ if and only if $x=1$ or $\log x=-\dfrac32$. However, $y$ has no local minimum at $1$, since its Taylor series there is$$(x-1)^3+\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^4-\frac{1}{4} (x-1)^5+\cdots$$On the other hand, if $\log x=-\dfrac32$, then $x=\dfrac1{\sqrt{e^3}}$, and$$y''\left(\frac1{\sqrt{e^3}}\right)=\frac92.$$Therefore $y$ has a local minimum at $\dfrac1{\sqrt{e^3}}$.

Comment: why after comparing to 0 , I can't remove the x's in the equation. x by definition of ln is not equal to zero therefore I am allowed to reduce it

Comment: You can devide by $x$, yes, while solveing the equation $y'=0$. That doesn't change the fact that you are wrong when you state that $y'=2\ln^2x+3\ln^2x$.

Comment: why not? putting x as 1 in the equation gives 3*0+2*0=0 which satisfies the equation

Comment: OP has a good point here, no?

Comment: There are two critical points, but only one is a local min.

Comment: yes I was wrong about the statement. ut why after comparing it to 0, it is not true? I didnt change the function after diving by x because x is not equal to 0...

Comment: @user6394019 You are right: $x=1$ is a solution too. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: @user6394019 See my previous comment: there are TWO critical points, but $x=1$ is not a local min.

Comment: @Randall thanks for the explanation. after I reached 2*(lnx)^3+3*(lnx)^2. I get 2 solutions. I dont know why I dismissed the part "local mimina"..

Comment: @user6394019 Done. What do you think now?

Answer (score 3):

Upon taking the first derivative carefully, you get
$$
y' = 2x\ln^3(x) + 3x\ln^2(x).
$$
My advice:  *Don't do any premature division by $x$ yet!*  Instead, factor out whatever you can:
$$
y'=x\ln^2(x)[2\ln(x) + 3].
$$
Now set each factor equal to $0$ and solve independently.  The first gives $x=1$ (your solution) while the second gives $x=e^{-3/2}$.

These are our only two critical points.  Now run the first derivative test around each critical point to see who is a local min (if any).  For this, using the factored form of $y'$ (the second one) is easier.  Around $x=1$ you get signs $+ +$ so there is no min/max there.  Around $x=e^{-3/2}$ you DO get a sign change $-+$ which indicates a local min.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the derivative is 
$$y'=2x \ln^3(x)+3x^2\ln^2(x)\,\frac1x.$$

Comment: I know. but after division of both 2x and 3x^2 by x, and then 3x divides by x.

Comment: Why can you just divide those out?   That changes the function.

Comment: change the fuction? x is not equal to 0 by definition of ln. therefore division by 0 is permitted

Comment: I think the root issue is actually that you're missing some terms, not that you're solving for critical points incorrectly.  I think we're both on the same page there.

Comment: The $1/x$ multiplies only the second term, not the first.